# Alternate User select interface in django admin to reduce page size on large site?

Tags: django, optimization, user-interface, autocomplete, django-admin

I have a Django-based site with roughly 300,000 User objects. Admin pages for objects with a ForeignKey field to User take a *very* long time to load as the resulting form is about 6MB in size. Of course, the resulting dropdown isn't particularly useful, either.

Are there any off-the-shelf replacements for handling this case? I've been googling for a snippet or a blog entry, but haven't found anything yet. I'd like to have a smaller download size *and* a more usable interface.

Comment: Check out Django 2.0's autocoomplete_fields feature.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The ModelAdmin class offers an 
[raw_id_fields](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.raw_id_fields) option, which present a input field and a search button. It presents a popup dialog to select the related user object without loading all

```
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    raw_id_fields = ("user",)
```