# Improving the loading performance of foreignkey fields with thousands of options

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a similar situation as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5108080/improving-performance-of-django-foreignkey-fields-in-admin) in which I encounter a slow page loading as I have thousands of entries in a foreignkey field.

At modelform, is there a way to improve the page loading while keeping the dropdown function? I have used [select2](https://select2.org/) to efficiently find the chosen item in the dropdown, thus want to keep this function.

Comment: While not keeping the dropdown, we've used `raw_id_fields` in cases like these, which is just one more click: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.raw_id_fields

Answer (score 0):

Django has to fetch all those foreignkey objects from database and then render them as HTML. This is why it takes a lot of time. Fetching from database can be pretty quick if you cache everything, but rendering to HTML will still be a problem.

Here's a solution that I think would work best:

1. Exclude that `ForeignKey` field from your form.
2. Instead, just create a blank input field. You'll have to capture user's input via JavaScript and send that value to your backed to fetch suggestions. In fact, [select2 supports fetching data from backend via AJAX](https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax), So, half of your work is done.
3. Create a view which will take that AJAX request and search the database for suggestions and send them back to the client.

And you're done.