# Django Admin on a very large database

Tags: python, django, database

Legacy DB with > 9mil records in a normalized DB, so multiple tables.

When loading a table that has ForeignKeys to also very large tables, my newly installed (legacy DB adapted), Django admin is unusable slow - dead slow.

Reason is simple, when trying to load the admin page, the ForeignKey table is being loaded to shove into a menu in the admin screen.  This SQL fails to load quickly enough.   Even if it did finish loading, the menu of items would be crazy huge, and not a suitable widget for the user.

So ... has anyone else faced this and solved it?  Perhaps there way to replace the menu with a filtered lookup?  Any other clever solutions to this?   Maybe a whole project could be created devoted to Django and the Admin on a large database.

Comment: Do you really need to modify that FK using Django admin? If not, you can hide that field by specifying `editable = False` in your model.

Comment: Good point.  Might do that now.   But there are a number of large FK tables all related to each other, and I'm betting that at some point, someone will want to edit something.   So, having a new widget to popup and search would be great.   (I'm mainly asking here to see if such a thing exists, or something better.  If not, I might built it.)

Comment: It depends on your exact needs. For starters, you can have a look at [formfield_for_foreignkey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey).

Comment: Look at http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html#using-autocompletes-in-the-admin. Autocomplete widget instead of default select is the best choice.

Comment: autocomplete looks nice, thanks.   tried it out, works as described.   would like to see the edit and new icons, going to try to add those.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alternate User select interface in django admin to reduce page size on large site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837036/alternate-user-select-interface-in-django-admin-to-reduce-page-size-on-large-sit)

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use [raw_id_fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.raw_id_fields).

Comment: Wouldn't it have a reverse effect?

Comment: @shlomoa Some users my prefer the standard widget to the "raw_id" one. I not know any other negative side effect.